# Objective-C How to check if keychain item is null (objectForKey)

Tags: objective-c, string, null, keychain

When I launch my app, I want to check if there are any stored credentials in the keychain, so I'm trying this :

```
- (BOOL)areStoredCredentials {
if(![keychain objectForKey:(id)kSecAttrAccount]) return NO;
else{
    NSLog(@"STORED CREDENTIALS : %@ / %@", [keychain objectForKey:(id)kSecAttrAccount], [keychain objectForKey:(id)kSecValueData]);
    self.login = [keychain objectForKey:(id)kSecAttrAccount];
    self.password = [keychain objectForKey:(id)kSecValueData];
    return YES;
}}
```

But this functions never returns NO even when the stored credentials are null. It even prints:

2011-11-13 21:58:07.205 NeroApp[541:f803] STORED CREDENTIALS :  /

Does anybody know why ?

Comment: Can you show us the code that produces that `keychain` object? I assume it's a result dictionary from `SecItemCopyMatching`, is that right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are getting empty strings from the keychain. You may try this kind of check:

```
if (![[keychain objectForKey:(id)kSecAttrAccount] length]) return NO;
else {
    ...
}
```